# Jquery UI tabs ,the tab select is inconsistent after rearranging the tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am using Jquery UI tabs for a wizard applictaion .After rearranging the tabs (part of the client requirement),the select index is inconsistent.We cannot allow jquery sortable on the tabs since only some tabs can be rearranged and the tabs do have a context menu too.So I am using insertAfter and insertBefore commands after it is rearranged successfully at server side.
In the fiddle the tabs are rearranged after button click :-

[Jquery Tabs Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74t3sf9p/8/)

```
     $("#btn").click(function(){
     $("#tabs ul li:nth-child(3)").after($("#tabs ul li:nth-child(1)"));

 });
```

Refreshing the tabs after rearranging is not an option for us.Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the `select` event first, returns the active tab, and then changes which tab is active. You won't receive the correct value if that is the case. You should instead use the `activate` event:

**Javascript:**

```
 $(function() {
     $("#btn").click(function(){
         $("#tabs ul li:nth-child(3)").after($("#tabs ul li:nth-child(1)"));
     });
  });

$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    activate: function(event,ui){
         var selected = $(ui.newTab).index();
         alert(selected);
    }
});
```

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74t3sf9p/9/)**

**EDIT:**
You can use `index` instead of `active` to find which tab is which based on it's position in the DOM.

Comment: I know about the select event .Even when returning previous tab it was not returning correctly.In your case it is working because of the refresh.We cannot refresh the tabs because of the huge amount of data postback to server.I have edited the fiddle

Comment: I wasn't talking about the `select` event. I was talking about the **[activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)** event. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by refresh. This code is identical to yours, other than the event type.

Comment: $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "refresh" );

Comment: Sorry..My mistake.I forgot  to save the fiddle after last edit.The refresh is not in the fiddle in the link now.The select is not consistent without it

Comment: It's all good. Doesn't refresh just recalculate the tabs themselves?

Comment: yes..it recalculates but refresh also postbacks to server if the tabs are jquery ajax loads.In our scenario we cannot afford to postback to the server

Comment: Damn, that sucks. Sorry I could help

Comment: I just updated my answer. Seems as though this will work without refreshing the tabs.

Comment: Thankyou..It works for sure but I already went with another solution to get index based on dom position :-   var curTab = $('.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)');